# Visualstudio 2015 Unable to get document https://localhost:44300/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration"

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I am using ASP.Net 4.5 and using .Net Framework 4.5.1 The application was working fine locally. after my recent installation of .net core 2.0, i am getting the following error. Not sure what has gone wrong.

Does anyone come across this similar?

```
Unable to get document https://localhost:44300/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration"

{"IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44300/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'."}
```

I am getting this exception in startup.cs, and the code is:

```
    app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = Constants.IdSrv,
        RequiredScopes = new[] {"web_api"}
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you migrate to .net core you must use Meadleware for identity server 4. but you use basic auth.

```
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_currentEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Cert\\Cert.pfx"), "123456");
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApisResources())
                .AddSigningCredential(cert)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();


public class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            };
        }
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApisResources()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                // simple API with a single scope (in this case the scope name is the same as the api name)
                new ApiResource("API", "api system"),

            };
        }


        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "UI",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 300,

                    AllowOfflineAccess=true,
                    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 999999,
                    RefreshTokenUsage=TokenUsage.ReUse,
                    AccessTokenType=AccessTokenType.Jwt,

                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secretKey".Sha256())
                    },

                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        "API",
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: @No i didnt migrated this project. this still running in .net 4.5